# Pass to javascript variable attribute from html input id="attribute"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input

```
<input type="text" value="" id="row1">
<input type="text" value="" id="row2">
```

Need to get last character from row and pass it to javascript variable. Here is row1 and row2, need to get variables 1 and 2

I try to use this, but does not work

```
$('[id^="row"]').each(function (index, row) {
var row = row.id.substring(3);
alert (row);//this is only to check if value exists (alert or not)
});
```

No alert at all. But need: on first iteration (.each) var row is 1, on second, - 2, etc.

Used this as example. The example works, but my code not

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) {
alert(index + ': ' + value);
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Your code seems to , but you don't mention it and didn't use the `jquery` tag...

Comment: The code is correct. Most likely it's not in a document ready handler, and it is loaded before the actual HTML

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/. It explains how to set up your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, **provided** that:

1. You are actually including jQuery at some point (you didn't mention it in your question, but you appear to be using it)
2. You run the code **after** the elements exist.

Here's your code with jQuery included and where we ensure that the code doesn't run until after the elements exist: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/avavuh/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/avavuh/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" value="" id="row1">
  <input type="text" value="" id="row2">
  <script>
    (function($) {
        $('[id^="row"]').each(function (index, row) {
        var row = row.id.substring(3);
        alert (row);//this is only to check if value exists (alert or not)
        });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how the `script` tag is *after* the elements it operates on, so they exist when that script runs.

This would **not** work:

```
  <script>
    (function($) {
        $('[id^="row"]').each(function (index, row) {
        var row = row.id.substring(3);
        alert (row);//this is only to check if value exists (alert or not)
        });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
  <input type="text" value="" id="row1">
  <input type="text" value="" id="row2">
```

...because when the script runs, the elements don't exist yet.

If for some reason you're not in control of where the `script` element goes, you can use jQuery's `ready` function to wait to run your code until the DOM has been loaded. But there's no need to do that if you control where the `script` tags go, just put them at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

More:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure Library engineers on when DOM elements are ready](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

Comment: Thanks, your code works. I will compare with my code (to understand).

Comment: @user2360838: The main thing is to make sure the script isn't run until after the elements exist. I've added an anti-example to demonstrate. Best,

Comment: One more question. I use $('[id^="row"]').each(function (index, row) { in one autosave script with save interval and one condition. And javascript code is above html input. However javascript works. Is it because of save interval and condition? I mean, page loads. At page load condition is not true and save interval time is not passed. And javascript starts to work only after page is loaded?

Comment: @user2360838: As long as the element exists when the `$(...)` call is made to find it in the DOM, it'll find the element. Script code is run as the `script` elements are encountered, but naturally anything scheduled (via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) or run in response to an event occurring happens later.